# How does online wallets handle ERC20 tokens behind the scenes?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet

Described in the title: **How do online wallets handle ERC20 tokens behind the scenes?**

Or centralised exchanges in that matter. Are they simply communicating with the ethereum blockchain to generate an account and then storing the private key for each user?

Hopefully someone can give an in-depth answer to this question and the technicalities behind.

Comment: What is `Pk` and `Sk`. Sorry, don't know what that is.

Comment: Furthermore, have a read on this Bitcoin SE [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/56573/how-do-exchanges-store-and-transfer-bitcoin). Qualify stuff.